# Differential of f(x,y)

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

How do I find the differential $Df(a,b)$ for the function $f:R^2\to R^3$ given by $f(x,y) = (xe^y+\cos y,x,x+e^y)$.

I have already done this for the differential $Df(0,0)$ but don't know how to do the above one

Comment: Find the partials.  Evaluate them at $(a,b)$.  Stick them [in a matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant).  Alternatively you can write it in function notation as $$[Df(a,b)](x,y) = \left(\color{red}{\left.\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x}\right|_{(a,b)}x + \left.\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial y}\right|_{(a,b)}y}, \color{purple}{\left.\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x}\right|_{(a,b)}x + \left.\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial y}\right|_{(a,b)}y}, \color{blue}{\left.\frac{\partial f_3}{\partial x}\right|_{(a,b)}x + \left.\frac{\partial f_3}{\partial y}\right|_{(a,b)}y}\right)$$

Comment: May I ask how you did it for $(0,0)$? You should be able to use the same method...

Answer (score 0):

$$ \Delta f = \frac{\partial f} {\partial x} dx +  \frac{\partial f} {\partial y} dy $$

In the above just find partial derivative values at $x=a, y=b$ instead of at $(x=0,y=0)$.

Here we have to  take all partials for each of three $f$ components as Bye_World indicates in comments below.. 9 quantities in all.

Comment: Note for readers: because $f$ is a vector-valued function, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ are vectors with $3$ components each.